# Dataframe count items per basket

Tags: dataframe, group-by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Order Date': [1-1-21, 1-1-21, 1-1-21, 1-1-21, 1-1-21, 1-2-21, 1-3-21, 1-3-21, 1-3-21],
         'Invoice No': [A1, A1, A2, A2, A2, B3, C1, C1, C2],
         'Product': ['eggs', 'ice', 'candy', 'toy', 'paper', 'book', 'computer', 'mouse', 'shoe'],
         'Warehouse': ['LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA']
         })
```

Hi all, I would like to group the items by date, and also count the item per basket.
On Jan 1 I sold 5 (2+3) items average of 2.5, where as Jan 2 of 1 item, and Jan 3 of items per basket in 2 in NY and 1 in LA.

Desired outcome:

```
           LA             NY
Jan 1      2.5            0
Jan 2      0              1
Jan 3      1              2
```

I have tried df.groupby(['Order Date', 'Warehouse']).count().unstack(), I want something like nunique().

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = df.groupby(["Order Date", "Warehouse"])["Invoice No"]

df_res = (
    (g.count() / g.nunique())
    .reset_index()
    .pivot(index="Order Date", columns="Warehouse")
    .fillna(0)
)

print(df_res)
```

Prints:

```
           Invoice No     
Warehouse          LA   NY
Order Date                
2021-01-01        2.5  0.0
2021-01-02        0.0  1.0
2021-01-03        1.0  2.0
```